# What javascript libraries can make a radial convergence graph?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, visualization

What JavaScript libraries can make a radial convergence graph?
Or, if no JavaScript libraries exist for it, what tools (preferably web technologies) can be used to make graphs similar to [this](http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/index.cfm?method=Radial%20Convergence)?

Ideally, I'd like for the output to be zoomable, as there are instances where there will be 200+ "nodes" on the circumference of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/). A great drawing framework...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://thejit.org/

Answer (score 1):

Two top-notch libraries for data visualization are

- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/), some examples of [radial charts](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/) are shown on the example page;
- [d3.js](https://d3js.org/), again with a great [example gallery](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/) but no radial chart available yet.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Chart API is great for this sort of thing.  I'd look into their **[Radar Chart](http://code.google.com/intl/ja/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/radar_charts.html)**.

Comment: sadly this API is deprecated